# DocumentSnapshot returning null and new screen stuck on loading

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

When this widget is called, its stuck on loading animation, and when hot reloaded, it shows the transactions
`

```
class TransactionList extends StatefulWidget {
  final int groupIndex;
  final String groupUid;

  const TransactionList(
      {super.key, required this.groupIndex, required this.groupUid});

  @override
  State<TransactionList> createState() => _TransactionListState();
}

class _TransactionListState extends State<TransactionList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final groupTransaction = Provider.of<DocumentSnapshot?>(context);

    if (groupTransaction == null) return const Loading();
    return transactionItemsBuilder(groupTransaction);
  
  }`
```

edit:
this is firebase instance created,

```
class DatabaseServices {
  final String? uid;

  DatabaseServices({this.uid});

  final CollectionReference groupCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups');

Stream<DocumentSnapshot> get transactions {
    return groupCollection.doc(uid).snapshots();
  }
}
```

and this is my stream provider

```
StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot?>.value(
              initialData: null,
              value: DatabaseServices(uid: widget.item[widget.index].id)
                  .transactions,
              child: TransactionList(
                  groupIndex: widget.index,
                  groupUid: widget.item[widget.index].reference.id),
            ),
```

Comment: could you add the part call Firestore?

Comment: instead of calling `return groupCollection.doc(uid).snapshots();`, call `return groupCollection.doc(uid).get();`

Comment: that solves my problem but I need the values to be updated in Realtime. By using return `groupCollection.doc(uid).snapshots();` , the widget was updating automatically when the values were changed in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by providing initial data to the stream provider. The data was obtained earlier.